# How to validate min and max length on value attribution using StringValidator attribute?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to validate a string value property length on attribution when the StringValidator attribute is defined as bellow?

```cs
[StringValidator(MinLength = 0, MaxLength = 100)]
public string CommercialName { get; set; }
```

I have checked extensively .NET Framework documentation but I was unable to find a solution. The objective would be to raise an exception when the value length is out of the defined range.

Comment: Client or server side validation?

Comment: @jcruz, not in a client/server context but rather in a shared library context to be referenced by other applications where this restriction could prevent out of range lengths when saving values in a database.

Comment: Please provide a full example. You need to show whether you are using Entity Framework or whatever and how you are calling the validation.

Comment: @jcruz, I'm not using Entity Framework, neither I'm in a ASP.NET context. I'm just building a class with properties and I would like to know if there is a way to implement a unique property validator method and use the StringValidator data in it. This way I wouldn't have to have a property by property validator in the class or a full property implementation.